# Synology disk mirror SHR or RAID 1

Tags: raid, network-attached-storage, raid1, synology

I created a mirrored volume on my Synology DS415+ created with two equal disks. The default mode was Synology Hybrid RAID (SHR) but I see that I could also could have chosen for 'regular' RAID 1.

As the disk currently only contains data that I can easily restore I thought if now is the time to recreate the volume to regular RAID 1.

Would that be a smart thing to do? Will that increase compatibility with other OS's?

I understand that the created volume would still be in ext4

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend leaving it as SHR. If anything, [Synology SHR](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/tutorials/492) actually *increases* the amount of storage space you can use while still giving you the same level of redundancy.